# Connecting draggable mobile UIbuttons connected via a line

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

How do I connect for two mobile (draggable) UIButtons with a line?

The problem: when I connect it looks pretty good, but when I try to drag one button the line stays in the same position.

I want to do something like Discover Music or Discover Apps, to build mobile graph with UIButtons as nodes.

Here is an example of my code:

```
- (CGRect)currentRect {
return CGRectMake (firstTouch.x,
firstTouch.y,
lastTouch.x - firstTouch.x,
lastTouch.y - firstTouch.y);
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
self.currentColor = [UIColor redColor];

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, currentColor.CGColor);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, currentColor.CGColor);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, firstTouch.x, firstTouch.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, lastTouch.x, lastTouch.y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
firstTouch = [touch locationInView:self];
lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self];

redrawRect = CGRectUnion(redrawRect, self.currentRect);
redrawRect = CGRectInset(redrawRect, -2.0, -2.0);
[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:redrawRect];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self];

redrawRect = CGRectUnion(redrawRect, self.currentRect);
[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:redrawRect];
}
```

[Screenshot](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/For_All/d3270cfac844faec52ce4aa6e81a6d41.png?w=256be1e8)

Comment: if you detect a move of that buttons all adjacent edges/lines have to be modified too. What do you mean with "when I connect it [Line with UIButton]"?

Comment: Right=) I thought in the same way, but there is a problem. When I did it, appears a new line but i can't delete previous. So as a result there are 2 lines and one line was between UIButton which didn't move and empty space.

Comment: ok, then some code would be nice to see

Comment: Now you can see code. When I'm trying to draw new line, previous don't disappear.

Comment: Have u tried just using setneedsdisplay without the rect? Perhaps since u give it the rect it's just redrawing that part of the screen and so the old line which might not be there, doesn't get redrawn

Comment: What would help your case here is to provide screenshots of before and after to help us visualise this problem.

Comment: 2 Daniel: yes i'm also tried without rect  - the same result.

Comment: Oops=) I have not enough reputation to post screenshot. http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=ba49d18367c73a4daab8861699a81c85

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should clear the context first. try:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);

    self.currentColor = [UIColor redColor];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, currentColor.CGColor);
    //...
```

I've not tested the code but it should help

Comment: Thanks! Looks good, but I have found solve by myself: In the implemention add background color and all works fine. Funny=)